# Shiny conditionalPanel always appears

Tags: shiny

I built a small application making use of a conditional Panel which worked out of the box.

A second attempt has been less satisfying.  The issue is that the conditional panels both show up no matter whether the conditions are met or not.

Here's what I have in a stripped down version:

```
 library(shiny)
 source('distplot.r')
 ui<-fluidPage(
 fluidRow(

 radioButtons("intype", 'Data or Statistics?',
         c(Data="d", Statistics="s")),

 #Only show this if sample data are to be entered     
 conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input$intype == 'd'",
      textInput('x', 'Sample Data (Comma Separated)', value='')),

#Only shows this panel for summary statitics (sd or sigma if known)
conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input$intype == 'r'",
        numericInput('m','Sample Mean',value=''),
        numericInput('sd','SD (Population or Sample)',value=''),
        numericInput('n','Sample size',value=''))
          )
             )       

 server<-function(input, output){

     DTYPE<-eventReactive(input$go,{input$dtype})
     output$plot<-renderPlot({hist(runif(1000))})
                        }
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

The two conditional panels always appear no matter the value of `input$intype`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `input.intype` and not `input$intype` in your condition. Moreover `intype` can only be `'d'` or `'s'` in your example, and you use `'r'` in your condition.

Details section from `?shiny::conditionalPanel` :

> In the JS expression, you can refer to input and output JavaScript objects that contain the current values of input and output. For example, if you have an input with an id of foo, then you can use **input.foo** to read its value. (Be sure not to modify the input/output objects, as this may cause unpredictable behavior.)